# Hitting the Google Analytics API with R using googleAnalyticsR doesn't bring in "not set" dimensions

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use googleAnalyticsR function google_analytics() to retrieve session-level data with 5 dimensions from GA. When I include the "mobileDeviceInfo" dimension in there, the results totally exclude any session that does not have a value for this dimension, namely, any desktop session.

Is there some option in this function to bring in "not set" dimension values as such along with the rest of the fields, instead of filtering them out?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `includeEmptyRows` option to `TRUE` ([`v3`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#includeEmptyRows), [`v4`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.include_empty_rows)). I had a quick look and couldn't find that option in `googleAnalyticsR`, although it might be there if you search more thoroughly. The alternative is to use a package like [`get_ga`](https://rdrr.io/cran/RGA/man/get_ga.html).

Comment: There is an includeEmptyRows=TRUE option in the new version of googleAnalyticsR apparently, but the Google API docs say this option only has to do with filtering out metrics that have null values. It doesn't seem to affect the null dimension filtering. 

I am just going to do some joins instead, I guess. Not a big problem. Thanks anyway.